# Authorization Bearer after basic

Tags: express, axios

I have backend server "protected" with basic http auth and exposed number of REST API endpoint. Some endpoint protected with JWT token that acquired on login process. JWT token sends from client in `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header.

Question: is it possible to have both auth types in the same moment - http auth and JWT? Only pass `Bearer` in different header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your backend. You will need to modify it a bit.

### Solution with passport-jwt

You can specify the `Bearer` Authorization header with a different name, like `X-Authorization` and then have somewhere ( let's assume you use [passport](https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt#extracting-the-jwt-from-the-request) ) configured that the JWT will be delivered via another request header

```
const jwt = ExtractJwt.fromHeader( "X-Authorization" );
```

Then the two headers won't collide and you will be able to have a user authenticated with JWT and / or Basic Auth.

Even if you are not using passport for JWT authorization, the basic idea is still valid.

### Generic solution

Or you can simply use a middleware to extract the authorisation. Similar to how [`express-bearer-token`](https://github.com/tkellen/js-express-bearer-token/blob/master/index.js) works.

```
app.use( function( req, res, next ) {

    var headerName = "X-Authorization";

    if (req.headers && req.headers[headerName]) {
        var parts = req.headers[headerName].split(' ');
        if (parts.length === 2 && parts[0] === "Bearer") {
            req["token"] = parts[1];
        }
    }

    next();

} );
```

Comment: Thank you. It could be the case. I am using another package - `express-bearer-token` and found that it able to extract token according to RFC - from request body or query string.

Comment: Updated my answer. The idea is to just take the parts of that module that work for you :)

Comment: Ok, it is not exactly answer to my question. but I already found solution. Marked this as answer  to whom it may concern.

Comment: You can always share how you solved it, by submitting an answer to your own question. Cheers.